# Why are some Bash commands both built-in and external?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

Some commands are internal built-in Bash commands while others are external (other programs). I see why certain commands need to be built-in. Some of the reasons are:

1. If a command needs to change the internal state of the shell process.
2. If a command performs a very basic operation in the shell.
3. If a command is called often and needs to be made fast. An external command is executed by loading an external program and hence is slower.

But why are some commands both built-in and external, for example *[echo](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo)* and *[test](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test)*? I understand *echo* is used a lot and thus is built-in (Reason 3). But then why also have it as an external command and have a binary for it in */bin/echo*? The built-in version of *echo* will always take precedence over the external version and thus, the external version is hardly ever used. So, why then have an external version of it at all?

Comment: Consider also that `bash` is not the only shell out there. At some point in its history `bash` may have decided to make a command internal, e.g. for reason #3 - but there are still other shells invoking the tool, so it has to continue existing as an external command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's exactly your point 3. When a command does very little (`echo` is a good example), spawning a new process dominates the run time behavior. With growing disks and bandwidth and code bases you always reach a spot when you have so much data and so many files (our code base at work has 100k files!!) that one less spawn per file makes a difference of minutes.

That's also why the typical built-in is a drop-in replacement which takes (perhaps a superset of) the same arguments as the binary.

You also ask why the old binary is still retained even though Bash has it as a built-in — the answer is that a lot of programs rely on the existence of that `/bin/echo`. It's actually [standardized](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html).

Bash is only one of many user interfaces and offline command interpreters. They all have different sets of built-ins. Some shells are purposefully small and rely a lot on what you could call "legacy" binaries. One example is [`ash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell) and its successor, [Dash](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-dash/). Dash is now the default `/bin/sh` in Ubuntu and Debian due to its speed, and is popular for embedded systems due to its small size. (But even Dash has builtins for `echo`, `test` and dozens of other commands, and provides a command history for interactive use.)

Comment: But why not have it only as an internal command then, like cd? What's the purpose of making it external as well?

Comment: Fedora (and RHEL?) does have an external /bin/cd script which simply calls the /bin/sh builtin cd command. It's only purpose, as far as I can tell, is to check whether a "cd" command will succeed, without actually changing directories in the current shell.

Comment: Hey @PeterMortensen, thanks for the edit -- I suppose it (marginally) improves the answer. But out of curiosity: Do you routinely go through old answers and improve them?